# Why is it often the "large" one between the two words for a polar dimension that is marked?

Tags: pragmatics

When we talk about a dimension neutrally, we usually say:
"How large is it?"
"How long is it?"
"How many did you buy?"
"How tall is the cup?"
"How heavy is the box?"
rather than "small, short, few, low, light".

Comment: Paraphrase: Why is "now normal is it" not a good question, and "how strange is it" a good one?